# "Cannot read property 'create' of undefined" error in Sequelize node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, migration, sequelize.js

I am working with node, sequelize, migration and mysql. I have already donde the sequelize init and define my models in the file of 'models'. I am testing my first endpoint in the server.js file but when I want run the post it appear the next message :

"Cannot read property 'create' of undefined"

I have read a lot of issues and it is suposed that with the next require y can access my model.

const User = require('./models').User

---

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const User = require('./models').User; 
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));


app.post('/new', function(req, res){
User.create({ 

   ....

}).then((user) => {

   ....

})}
app.listen(8000)
```

Comment: Please share the code of user model.

Comment: model name User, may not match with the name that is defined in the models/user.js file or if there are any changes made to the models/index.js file this error might occur.

Comment: I have already fixed it !! Thank you !!

Comment: just a suggestion, put your Fix here when you resolve your problems... you problem can by my problem too